# Adding editText on button click

Tags: android, eclipse

I have a layout (activity_main.xml) that has some TextView and EditText elements and a button.
I have some stuff happen when the button is clicked, but I want to add a new EditText element directly below and existing element after the button has been clicked.

How can I make this happen please?

Comment: `Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.`

Comment: Not a good question,show your effort.

Comment: I have tried various options from code samples that I have found but cannot get them to function correctly. I'm not sure what code I can show as I have tried various options without success.
In several cases the code would compile but when executing nothing would happen.
I am an experienced coder but still learning Java for android. Sorry I don't have more for you.
Most of what I have doe has been longhand and I'm hoping to learn how to simplify my code.

Comment: Please don't put such question here

Comment: Fine. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: This is exactly about not wasting anyone's time, neither the poster's nor the ones that answer. To help this, how about linking all the tutorials you have tried and mention for each of them, why it didn't work for you or why was it not doing what you expected?. It might take a bit of work to re-do your steps, but it makes it much easier for someone to answer correctly, which in the end is what we all what. So how about editing the question and explaining it with a bit more specifics?

Comment: No problem. I'll keep that in mind for next time.  Fortunately, Milanor has given me something that does work and now has me back on track with my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually i just play around with the Visibility of the elements. Example:

on OnCreate: `EditText1.setVisibility(GONE);`

and then on your OnClickListener Implementation:

```
private OnClickListener onShow = new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        EditText1.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

This will hide your EditText (or whatever element you want) in the creation of the activity, and then show them again when you pressed the button.

The above mentioned method is easier and it seems suffice enough for most of my projects. However, if we really want to add elements dynamically, there is a way.

We can basically add any element dynamically to our xml layout. But we need an element (container) in our xml layout for holding our added element later. Example, we use an empty LinearLayout with android:id="@+id/container". With this in mind, it means we can build everything dynamically from scratch and setContentView(ourView), where ourView is the root element with other child elements added.

Example:

```
EditText newElement = new EditText(this);
newElement.setLayoutParams(params);
LinearLayout container = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.container);
container.addView(newElement);
```

Note: This is just a pseudocode and not a complete code.

Comment: Thanks for that. I'll consider this option but I'd really like to be dynamically add new fields as required.

Comment: try checking out my edited answer, i added the second option on how to add element dynamically. Maybe it can help :)

Comment: glad to be of help :)

Comment: I want to implement this can you please see my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73090637/6854117)?