# Create Linear Layout programmability on button click in android studio

Tags: java, xml, android-studio, android-recyclerview, android-linearlayout

I am working on `android studio`. I have created a linear layout inside a fragment like below :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/ll_out"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@drawable/background_round"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="5sp">


            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <AutoCompleteTextView
                    android:id="@+id/tv_product"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
                    android:gravity="left"
                    android:inputType="text"
                    android:hint = "Enter Product"
                    />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="10sp"
                android:orientation="horizontal">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/prod_qty"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:focusable="true"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
                        android:hint="Enter Quantity"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:inputType="number" />
                </LinearLayout>
                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/prod_price"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Prod Price"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:inputType="none" />
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight=".5"
                    android:orientation="vertical">
                    <EditText
                        android:id="@+id/prod_specs"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:editable="false"
                        android:focusable="false"
                        android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
                        android:hint="Prod Specs"
                        android:gravity="left"
                        android:inputType="none" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
                android:padding="0dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/btn_prd"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Add New Product"
                    android:textColor="@color/white" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
```

**GUI**

[image]

**What do I want to do?**

On clicking of `Add New Product` button, I want to recreate the same Linear Layout along with the `textviews`.

In the above image, the product names, price, and specs are taken out from the `JSON` file which is stored in the user mobile.

**What I have Tried**

Below is the code that I have tried to do

```
addProduct.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Add product button click  " , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            LinearLayout linearLayoutProduct = new LinearLayout(getActivity());
            linearLayoutProduct.findViewById(R.id.ll_out);//Stuck here 
        }
    });
```

**Update 1**

I want to make the app like following

[image]

In the above picture when I click the `plus` sign then a new row is created with the `cross` button and so on. I want exactly the same

How can I do this?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why load the layout into memory again? Why reload the whole activity when you're already in it?
How I would approach this. On successful save, prompt user if they would like to create another 'booking'. If yes, then clear all fields, and move to top of the view.

Comment: @JonR85 the reason for doing this is that there can be more than one booking(s) per customer. So I have to add multiple products under one form

Comment: Than you would want a RecyclerView

Comment: @JonR85 can you please guide me ?

Comment: just remove the OLD View from the Parent Layout by view.remove(view) method and  add again that linear layout to parent view by initializing with new  Keyword.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar kindly see my updated question. You will get the idea what i want to achieve ?

Comment: @Moeez : Answer is same but for this you don't need to remove the view from parent layout.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar ok but can you pl share me the sample code??

Comment: @Moeez : Check my Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this You Need two separate layout, one is parent and another one is child layout. In parent there will be only LinearLayout and Another view will consist a custom layout which you want to add on this.

For Example follow this.

#### layout1.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
 
</LinearLayout>
```

And some other Layout like this:

#### layout2.xml

```xml
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
 
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="TextView 1" />
 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 2" />
 
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button 3" 
        android:layout_weight="1"/>
 
</LinearLayout>
```

You can inflate the `layout2.xml` file, edit the texts, and add it to the first layout:

```java
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

        private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,  Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.yourMainLayout, container, false);
            .
            .
            .
            mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);
            Button fab = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.fab);
            fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
              @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                  // new elements on click
                  addLayout("This is text 1", "This is first button", "This is second Button");
            }
        });
            addLayout("This is text 1", "This is first button", "This is second Button");
        }

        private void addLayout(String textViewText, String buttonText1, String buttonText2) {
            View layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.layout2, mLinearLayout, false);

            TextView textView = (TextView) layout2.findViewById(R.id.button1);
            Button button1 = (Button) layout2.findViewById(R.id.button2);
            Button button2 = (Button) layout2.findViewById(R.id.button3);

            textView1.setText(textViewText);
            button1.setText(buttonText1);
            button2.setText(buttonText2);

            mLinearLayout.addView(layout2);
        }
```

You may want to change `android:layout_height` of the `layout2.xml` root view to `wrap_content`.

**Here I haven't taken the Button in XML LAYOUT, you can put the Button according to your need.**

If you are using ViewBinding, here is how it would look like for the `addLayout` function :

```java
MyLayoutBinding binding = MyLayoutBinding.inflate(getLayoutInflater(), mLinearLayout, false);
binding.getTextView1().setText(textViewText);
binding.getButton1().setText(buttonText1);
binding.getButton2().setText(buttonText2);

mLinearLayout.addView(binding.getRoot());
```

In your Case you can call this method from onClick() of Add Button

```
addLayout("This is text 1", "This is first button", "This is second Button");
```

Comment: I am using fragments so how can I use the above in the same?

Comment: @Moeez : it will work on both Fragment and Activity, you can use this method anywhere.  private void addLayout(String textViewText, String buttonText1, String buttonText2)

Comment: what is `linear_layout` in `mLinearLayout = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.linear_layout);`??

Comment: Secondly, I am getting `cannot find symbol method setContentView` and `cannot find symbol method findViewById`

Comment: @Moeez : First one is, the ViewGroup is a LinearLayout, you can also replace it  with LinearLayout and Second One is You Don't need to use setContentView Method It's Activity Specific Method, you can Use the code below this line.

Comment: with ` mLinearLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.ll_prod);` now it's giving me `cannot resolve method findViewById in Fragment`

Comment: Where to use `MyLayoutBinding` ??

Comment: I have done like this `mLinearLayout = new LinearLayout(getContext()).findViewById(R.id.ll_prod);` but I am getting `null` in `mLinearLayout`

Comment: @Moeez : LinearLayout mLinearLayout = getActivity().findViewById(R.id. ll_prod); use this, on Fragment getActivity() will provide the context of Activity.

Comment: @Moeez : I am doing some change in place of Activity to Fragment. Please do that changes on your Code.

Comment: I am confused about `yourMainLayout` and `linear_layout`

Comment: @Moeez yourMainLayout is layout name for your fragment, and linear_layout is component where you want to add views.

Comment: ok got it let me check it today

Comment: can you please check my new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73208022/6854117)?

Comment: @Moeez : sure.....

Answer (score 1):

You should use RecylcerView for this.

Go in the android studio palate in the containers section and choose recycler view [section recyclerview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ONPN.png)

now go to the layout folder in the res folder and right click, go to the new and choose 'Layout Resource File' [Layout Resource File image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xzxnO.png)

and in there put the design you want with linear layout or constraint it doesn't (for your preferences)
here is a simple design for example:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="name"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_address"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="address"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tv_name" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

now after this, you have to add an adapter to this recyclerview
I suggest you watch some video's about recyclerview it will make your life much easier.
here is a nice video that I found https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FFCpjZkqfb0
and a documentation about it in android developers about it https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview?gclid=CjwKCAjw_b6WBhAQEiwAp4HyID37vUoVrC9qOdjgzxIzKXrv4kvtuN7A9XMRozB2wyQDgQ9BLqdpVRoCaBkQAvD_BwE&gclsrc=aw.ds