# Android studio app crashes on the button click

Tags: java, android-studio, android-fragments, android-edittext, parent-child

I am working on android studio. I have created some `fragments` and they are smoothly working. The app would be collecting data from users for order booking. Now, I have a button and on this button click, I am calling another layout to enter the products. The data is selected from the json file. Below is my code

**Fragment**

```
Button addProduct;
private LinearLayout mLinearLayout;
public View layout2;
public View view = null;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   if (view == null) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.new_survey_form_layout, container, false); // my main layout
        mLinearLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.ll_prod);// the layout in which I want to call my below layout
        layout2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_layout, mLinearLayout, false);// product layout


        this.initElements(view);// all of my fields against my new_survey_layout_form_layout
        this.initElementsPrd(layout2); // the fields of my second layout
    }
}

 private void initElementsPrd(View view) {
    productAuto = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_product);
    qtyEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.prod_qty);
    prodPriceEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.prod_price);
    prodSpecsEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.prod_specs);
    setProd();// to set the adapters for selecting the product name
}
 private void setProd()
{
    Log.d("Ali", "sub div");
    if (prodArrayList == null) {
        prodArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        Log.d("Ali", "prod new");
    } else {
        prodArrayList.clear();
        Log.d("Ali", "prod clear");
    }

    if (isNewSurvey) {
        prodArrayList.addAll(new ProductManager(getActivity()).getAvailableProducts());
        Log.d("Ali", "prod is new booking");
    } else {
        prodArrayList.addAll(new ProductManager(getActivity()).getProducts());
        Log.d("Ali", "sub div edit survey");
    }
    if (prodAdapter == null) {
        Log.d("Ali", "sub div new adapter");
        prodAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, prodArrayList);
        productAuto.setAdapter(prodAdapter);
    } else {
        Log.d("Ali", "sub div notify");
        prodAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

        addProduct.setOnClickListener(v -> {


        addLayout();

    });
```

Now when I click the add button for the first time it does show the layout of the product but when I click on the same button for the second time the app crashes. Below is the working

[image]

**Error Message**

> The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

**Solution Tried**

Inside add layout function I have done the following

```
 private void addLayout(){
    layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_layout, mLinearLayout, false);
    productAuto = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_product);
    qtyEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.prod_qty);
    prodPriceEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.prod_price);
    prodSpecsEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.prod_specs);

 }
```

The product form is shown every time when I click on the `Add new Product` button. But I can't select a product in this case.

**Update 1**

I have taken `addProduct` button in `this.initElements(view);`

```
private void initElements(View view) {

    newSurveyScrollview = (ScrollView) view.findViewById(R.id.new_survey_scrollview);
 refNofield1 = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.ref_no_field_1);
    consumerNameEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.consumer_name);
    consumerAddressEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.consumer_address);
    latitudeEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.latitude);
    longitudeEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.longitude);
    placeEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.place);
    subDivisionSpinner = (Spinner) view.findViewById(R.id.sub_division_spinner);
cameraButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.open_camera);
    saveButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.save_survey_form);
    resetButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.survey_reset);
    getRefNoButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.get_ref_no_button);
    getLatLangButton = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.get_lat_lang_button);
    addProduct = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.btn_prd);

}
```

**Error Log**

```
Process: com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey, PID: 6854
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:5038)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4869)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4809)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:4782)
    at com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey.fragments.SurveyFormFragment.addLayout(SurveyFormFragment.java:1904)
    at com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey.fragments.SurveyFormFragment.lambda$initListeners$1$com-example-thumbsol-accuratesurvey-fragments-SurveyFormFragment(SurveyFormFragment.java:550)
    at com.example.thumbsol.accuratesurvey.fragments.SurveyFormFragment$$ExternalSyntheticLambda3.onClick(Unknown Source:2)
    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6608)
    at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6585)
    at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:785)
    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25921)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6810)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873)
```

The error comes at below part

```
 private void addLayout() {

    mLinearLayout.addView(layout2);
}
```

**Update 2**

I have removed the second layout part from `onCreatView` and done the following

```
private void addLayout() {
   layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_layout, mLinearLayout, false);
    this.initElementsPrd(layout2);
    mLinearLayout.addView(layout2);
}
```

Below is what I am getting now

[image]

The autocomplete is working for the 1st one but for the second or 3rd upto `N` its not working.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: where you have taken addProduct button in layout? Share the crash logs exactly.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar I have updated my code pl check

Comment: share the crash logs exactly

Comment: @AniruddhParihar pl check

Comment: layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_layout, mLinearLayout, false);

on both places where inflating the view, don't pass the mLinearLayout as ViewGroup, Pass null instead of that.

Comment: @AniruddhParihar it does work but now I am unable to search any product. When I type in the name it doesn't gives me any product name

Comment: In other words now my auto complete text view is not working

Comment: it will not affect Auto Suggestion, if you think so then don't remove mLinearLayout from onCreateView Method.

Comment: I didn't remove it from onCreateView because I am passing the layout2 to my `this.initElementsPrd(layout2);` to render the fields from other layout

Comment: @AniruddhParihar can you pl check my new upated?

Comment: @Moeez Please check my answer whether you are missing the same thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the [Gowtham K K](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73265811/6854117) answer I have done the following changes in my code

```
private void addLayout() {
    layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_layout, mLinearLayout, false);
    productAuto = (AutoCompleteTextView) layout2.findViewById(R.id.tv_product);
    qtyEditText = (EditText) layout2.findViewById(R.id.prod_qty);
    prodPriceEditText = (EditText)layout2.findViewById(R.id.prod_price);
    prodSpecsEditText = (EditText)layout2.findViewById(R.id.prod_specs);
    removeProduct = (Button)layout2.findViewById(R.id.btn_rmv);
   
    setProd();
    
}
```

Then in my `setProd()` function

```
 prodArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (isNewSurvey) {
        prodArrayList.addAll(new ProductManager(getActivity()).getAvailableProducts());
        Log.d("Ali", "prod is new booking");
    } else {
        prodArrayList.addAll(new ProductManager(getActivity()).getProducts());
        Log.d("Ali", "sub div edit survey");
    }
    prodAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, prodArrayList);
    productAuto.setAdapter(prodAdapter);
```

Implementing the above solution my program is working now

Answer (score 1):

You are adding a layout by calling this method. But autocomplete textview will not work for the newly added layout because you haven't set the adapter to newly added Layout.
You need to call setProd() in addLayout() to bind adapter to autocomplete text view when new layout is added.

```
 private void addLayout(){
    layout2 = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.product_layout, mLinearLayout, false);
    productAuto = (AutoCompleteTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv_product);
    qtyEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.prod_qty);
    prodPriceEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.prod_price);
    prodSpecsEditText = (EditText)view.findViewById(R.id.prod_specs);
    setProd();
 }
```

> Note: For handling dynamic layouts it would be better to handle view object in a list and handle instead of reinstantiating every time to existing object.

Comment: how to `For handling dynamic layouts it would be better to handle view object in a list and handle instead of reinstantiating every time to existing object.` ?

Comment: I have tried your solution but it doesn't works